# How to rename multiple vars that contain FOR counter vars in bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Here is my sample:

```
set mail = mymail
for /L  %%x in (001,1,999) do (
    set yourmail = !mail:+%x@gmail.com
    :: other commands here
)
```

I want the result be like: mymail+001@gmail.com ----> mymail+999@gmail.com

the code block above will work good? tks.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are significant within SET statements. Your sample has defined a variable named "mail " with a space at the end, and the value equals " mymail" with a space in the front.

The simplest way to get all your numbers zero prefixed to length three is to add 1000 to everything and use a substring operation to take the last 3 digits.

```
set "mail=mymail"
for /l  %%x in (1001,1,1999) do (
  set "num=%%x"
  set "yourmail=!mail!!num:~-3!@gmail.com"
  :: other commands here
)
```